# Populating array with sequentially named ui objects from Qt form

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, qt-designer, boost-preprocessor

I have a Qt project with an ui made in Qt Designer. The ui currenlty contains 16 QLabels. I need to have an array with all of the QLabels. Currently I initialize the array with:

```
labels_ = {ui->label0, ui->label1, ui->label2, ui->label3, ui->label4,
           ui->label5, ui->label6, ui->label7, ui->label8, ui->label9,
           ui->label10, ui->label11, ui->label12, ui->label13, ui->label14,
           ui->label15};
```

I would like to be able to later easily add and remove QLabels to the ui form. What if at some point I would like to test the program with 100 QLabels?

I found out that with Boost.preprocessor I could achieve this:

```
#define NLABELS 16
#define FILL_ARRAY(z, idx, name) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(name, idx), 

labels_ = {BOOST_PP_REPEAT(NLABELS, FILL_ARRAY, ui->label)};
```

However, I am still hesitant whether this is the right approach or not. Maybe Qt has some other functionality to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Qt you can use the [findChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) function:

```
    QList<QLabel*> list = this->findChildren<QLabel*>(QRegularExpression("label\\d+$"));
```

This will return a QList of pointers to QLabels children of `this` that are named `labelX` (where `X` is at least one digit).

LE: By reading the comments i assume it's not sorted the way you want, so you can sort the strings numerically by using the [QCollator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcollator.html) like this:

```
QCollator c;
c.setNumericMode(true);

std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [&c](QLabel* lhs, QLabel* rhs) {
    if(c.compare(lhs->objectName(), rhs->objectName()) < 0)
        return true;
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This seems like something I was looking for, but will it guarantee that the objects are ordered by name? I.e. list[0] == ui->label0, list[1] == ui->label1, etc.?

Comment: I don't know the ordering of that list, it might be the order of creation (adding them in the layout). 

Anyway, as this is a one time operation you can sort the list as you want, in case you don't want to add boost as dependency.

Comment: You can do an additional steps which sorts the data

Comment: `qSort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](const QLabel* label1, const QLabel* label2){ return label1->objectName() < label2->objectName();})`

Comment: @UmNyobe That won't work because (QString("label2") < QString("label11")) == false

Comment: @user2563661 i added the sort too

Comment: @user2563661 Ohh nice catch. I forgot about this.

Comment: I think, in general, this is the correct answer so I will accept it. However, in my case where I need the array to be sorted and cannot guarantee in what order the labels are added to the layout, I feel like using Boost.preprocess makes the code overall simpler and more clear so I will stick with it.

Comment: @user2563661 Yes, however, if you add/remove labels often, this approach is better, because you don't have to remember to modify the define for the number of labels, it just works automatically as long as the label names keep the format. Also note that i added the sort too.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `std::vector<QLabel*>` instead and `push_back` each label at the time you create it? Possibly in a member function?

```
class C
{
    std::vector<QLabel*> labels;

public:
    void createLabel(char const* text)
    {
        QLabel* label; // create it as needed, add it to designated parent

        labels.push_back(label);

        // alternative: create it above without parent
        // and return it here (change signature appropriately)
    }
};
```

**Edit** in response to your comment:

For use from within QT designer, a custom label might help you out:

```
class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    static std::vector<MyLabel*> instances;

public:
    MyLabel(/* whatever you need */)
        : QLabel(/*...*/)
    {
        instances.push_back(this);
    }

    ~MyLabel()
    {
        instances.erase
        (
            std::remove(instances.begin(), instances.end(), this),
            instances.end()
        );
    }

    // static begin() and end() functions returning (const_)iterators to your vector
};
```

QT designer supports (to a certain degree at least) custom widgets, too, according to [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Comment: The QLabels are already in the Qt designer form, so aren't they automatically created when I call ui->setupUi(this)?

Comment: As speaking of 100+ labels, I assumed you were creating them programmatically... Using Qt designer, you might write your own label class inheriting from QLabel, provide it with a static vector and let each label add itself to that static vector during construction and remove itself again on destruction. For using these in the designer, see [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html).

Answer (score -1):

Seems correct for me, Qt has no functionality for this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16264266)

Comment: it's a correct answer for the question "does qt provides a way to do that?" and the answer is no, there isn't. There's no need to request clarification as the question is simple, Qt has no functionality to do what OP requested.